# VBA isnumber istext function problem

Tags: function, vba

im trying to check if a number is a text or number in a banking system. If the value is incorrect it should erase and send an error message, but my code isnt working at all... can someone help me? here is the code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

   name = TextBox1

   If Application.IsText(name) = True Then
      IsText = True
   Else
      MsgBox "Insert only words"
      Selection.name.Delete
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "my code isnt working at all". Where does the error occur? Don't keep us guessing...

Comment: You should have *Option Explicit* at the top of your module.  This will force you to declare the name var and ensure that TextBox1 is the actual Textbox you're referencing.

Comment: What application is hosting this VBA project? What library does the TextBox come from? Is it a UserForm TextBox? Access? Windows Forms? Other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using `name = TextBox1.Text` instead.  It's probably giving you an error on that line.

Also, you may want to wait until the user is finished typing the response, I believe the changed event will run each time a character is pressed.  The `AfterUpdate` will run after you tab or click away from the textbox.

And really, instead of deleting the response (which I don't think will work), you should simply set the textbox blank back to an empty string.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
    If Not MyIsANumber(TextBox1.Text) Then
        MsgBox ("It's Text")
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Function MyIsANumber(str As String) As Boolean
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(str, i, 1)) Then
           MyIsANumber = True
           Exit Function
        End If
    Next
        MyIsANumber = False
 End Function
```

I'm sure the code could be structured better, but there's something along the lines of what you need.  In this case, it just wipes the textbox if there is a number entered.  Obviously, things will need to be the opposite for your textbox that you want to contain a number.

Comment: well, i changed that but still doesnt work... the problem is that it simply does not generate erros, the code just doesnt work, nothing happens if a digit a number instead of a word. and how do i make it wait until everything is typed???

Comment: @Daniel See my edit, and see if you can come up with the custom is a number function.  I'll fill that in after a bit.

Comment: VB/VBA has [Default Properties](http://www.hitmill.com/programming/vb/defaultProp.html) so although it's good practice to code the Textbox's text property, _name = TextBox1_, will not cause an error.

Comment: @jonsca That's what you get for being a disciplined programmer :D

Comment: @jonsca it worked! i just did a small change and now it works perfectly! thxx 
heres how it is now:

Comment: Private Sub TextBox5_Change()

If MyIsANumber(TextBox5.Text) Then
        
        TextBox5.Text = ""
   
 End If

End Sub

Function MyIsANumber(str As String) As Boolean
    
For i = 1 To Len(str)
       
 If IsNumeric(Mid(str, i, 1)) Then
          
 MyIsANumber = True
          
 MsgBox "insert only words"
           
Exit Function
       
 End If
    
Next
        
MyIsANumber = False
 
End Function

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the vartype() function? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference. Perhaps expand your answer, and include an example.